# i have used grid view along with text view and image button now how to show button at the end of all these

Tags: android, gridview, textview, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

i have more than 40 rows with some text in each rows and i have used grid view along with text view some image button to show this

and these all are inside linear layout

now at the end of this i wanted to show button how can i put..

Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/yourGrid"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button 1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"    /> 
    <Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GridView"
    />
```